# Provide inheritance-like behavior for traits in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

So let's say I have two little traits, **Parser** and **Trigger**.
A **Parser** takes a slice of strings, do some parsing and returns the slice of strings without the consumed tokens. On error, it returns an error.
A **Trigger** is just like a **Parser**, except it does not expect any tokens, therefore it does something and maybe return an error. Every **Trigger** can be treated as a **Parser** and I want to define the function which makes that rule real. This is what my intuition would have me do:

```
pub trait Parser<'a> {
  fn parse(&mut self, &'a [String]) -> Result<&'a [String], Error>;
}

pub trait Trigger {
  fn pull(&mut self) -> Option<Error>;
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> for Trigger {
  fn parse(&mut self, tokens: &'a [String]) -> Result<&'a [String], Error> {
    match self.pull() {
      Some(err) => Err(err),
      _         => Ok(tokens) //Returns the tokens untouched
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
parsers.rs:37:33: 37:40 error: explicit lifetime bound required
parsers.rs:37 impl<'a> Parser<'a> for Trigger {
                                      ^~~~~~~
```

Can you please explain what is going on and what would be the idiomatic  way of achieving what I want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traits in Rust are not regular types. They either can be used as generic bounds or as trait objects, which *are* regular types but which also require some kind of indirection to work with them (a reference or a `Box`). You, on the other hand, are trying to implement `Parser` for bare `Trigger`. Bare traits are dynamically sized types and in general they can't be used everywhere where ordinary sized types can.

What you really want is to implement `Parser` *for every type which implements `Trigger`*. This can be written in a very straightforward way:

```
impl<'a, T> Parser<'a> for T where T: Trigger {
  fn parse(&mut self, tokens: &'a [String]) -> Result<&'a [String], Error> {
    match self.pull() {
      Some(err) => Err(err),
      _         => Ok(tokens)
    }
  }
}
```

This is so-called *blanket impl* pattern, and it is used widely across the standard library. There are limitations for it, though, for example, you won't be able to reimplement `Parser` for any particular `Trigger`.

BTW, consider moving `'a` lifetime argument in the trait to its method. The way you use this parameter is rarely useful (of course, it depends on your actual code, but still).

Comment: All right, thanks, that is pretty much what I was looking for. I will consider moving the lifetime parameter and see what happens :).